# Java/JPA database sequence number pool in memory

Tags: java, database, memory, sequence

Is there a good solution to implementing a pooled sequence number generator in memory?

I know that Hibernate/JPA includes a table generator id type, but unfortunately due to legacy reasons my webservice needs to be able to assign these ids in memory before the object is actually saved.

Is there a recommended approach to doing this? I'm sure many dangerous things can happen, regarding transaction rollbacks and what not. Does anyone have any advice or resources that can explain the best way to handle this?

Comment: Read the code of the seqhilo generator of Hibernate, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thats interesting I have never thought of that before. One thing that could possibly help is to use an [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) but that doesnt solve the issues with rolling back transactions.

Maybe a class wrapping something similar and keep a list of long values to hold rolled back keys which could be retrieved from first could work?

Another issue is you would need to get the maximum key value from your table (if you do something similar to what I described) to ensure no duplicate keys on your applications start.

I am not sure if this helps but it is a place to start.